# Python lambda doesn't remember argument in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, lambda

I'm working with python and trying to isolate a problem I had with lambda functions.

From the following code I was expecting to create two lambda functions, each getting a different x, and the output should be

```
1
2
```

but the output is

```
2
2
```

Why?
And how can I make two different functions? Using def?

```
def main():
    d = {}
    for x in [1,2]:
        d[x] = lambda: print(x)

    d[1]()
    d[2]()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Bad use of lamba. It just returns the turn value of print which is None. Print is supposed to be a command and not an expression.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The body of the `lambda` in your code references the name `x`.  The value associated with that name is changed on the next iteration of the loop, so when the lambda is called and it resolves the name it obtains the new value.

To achieve the result you expected, bind the value of `x` in the loop to a parameter of the `lambda` and then reference that parameter, as shown below:

```
def main():
    d = {}
    for x in [1,2]:
        d[x] = lambda x=x: print(x)

    d[1]()
    d[2]()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

>>> 
1
2
```

Comment: Python 3k+ only I think... Does not work (for me) in P2.7 but does in P3.2 and P3.3

Comment: @drewk:  This answer is applicable to any Python since the introduction of `lambda`.

Comment: @drewk good point:  the difference is that `print` is a statement in Python < 3 and so it isn't allowed in a `lambda`.  It is a function in Python 3, and so it is allowed there.

Comment: @drewk in 2.7 this version works (without print in lambda): http://ideone.com/IHrsk

Comment: If you're really worried about `print` in lambda, just use `sys.stdout.write(x+"\n")`

Comment: @mgilson `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`   .  you need to convert the integer.  This works for me with python 2.7:   `sys.stdout.write(str(x)+"\n")`

Comment: While the answer code is not wrong, I suggest changing the bound variable in the lambda to name it something else. For clarity improvement. I suggest:  `d[x] = lambda y=x: print(y)`   . (I tried editing the post but editing less than 6  characters is not allowed)

Comment: Thank you so much @applicative_functor and @dsh! This answer helped me solve an issue I've been trying to fix for three days!

Comment: Interestingly, PyCharm 2023.3 highlights the right-hand size of `x=x` as an "unsolved error", even though the code runs correctly with Python 3.12.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like work for [`partial`](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial).

```
from functools import partial 
def main():
    d = {}
    for x in [1,2]:
        d[x] = partial(lambda x: print(x), x=x)

    d[1]()
    d[2]()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: +1.  The simple way to do this is to write this as `d[x] = lambda x=x: print(x)`.  However, `partial` allows you to lock down the arguments.  This might be written better as `d[x] = partial(print, x)`, since `print` is a function.  No need to wrap it in a lambda.

Comment: Your comment is great! I wrote `lambda`, cause question about `lambda` :)

Answer (score 5):

This will fix it. It is because the x is directly bound to the lambda.

```
def create_lambda(x):
    return lambda : print(x)

def main():
    d = {}
    for x in [1,2]:
        d[x] = create_lambda(x)

    d[1]()
    d[2]()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```