# pyQt pushButton connect creation within loop

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, maya

I am new to pyqt (pyside in maya), please be nice to me :)

so the point is i want to generate many button via loop statement, something simmilar like below :

(5 button in a window - complete code - maya)

```
import PySide.QtCore as qc
import PySide.QtGui as qg
class simpleUI(qg.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        qg.QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Simple UI')
        self.btn=[]
        for x in range(5) :
           self.btn.append(x)
           self.btn[x]= qg.QPushButton(self)
           self.btn[x].setText('this is btn number{0}'.format(x))
           self.btn[x].setGeometry(qc.QRect(0,100+(x*20), 100,20))
           self.btn[x].clicked.connect(lambda : self.notifyMe(x))
    def notifyMe(self,index):
        print index
dialog = simpleUI()
dialog.show()
```

as you see, I store button object in array, but the problem is when i want to connect btn signal with *notifyMe function*, **every button always give x same  value (x=4)** , meanwhile in **button.setText** x succeed give unique incremental value, i can't figure it why..

**Edit:**

revisit this again after 6 years later, I wanna inform that I was always using partial rather than lambda, here is what I did on PySide2 / PyQt5:

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from functools import partial

class simpleUI:
    def __init__(self):
        app = QApplication()
        window = QMainWindow()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        for x in range(5):
            btn = QPushButton('this is btn number {0}'.format(x))
            btn.clicked.connect(partial(self.notifyMe, index=x))
            layout.addWidget(btn)
        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        window.setCentralWidget(widget)
        #
        window.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

    def notifyMe(self, index):
        print(index)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    simpleUI()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is old problem with function in `lambda` - it doesn't get value from `x` when you declare function but when you click button. But when you click button then `for-loop` is over and `x` keeps last value - and this way all buttons use the same value. You have to use

```
lambda a=x: self.notifyMe(a)
```

Comment: thanks furas, you explained perfectly !

Comment: I had to change it to also include the `checked` argument, that `clicked()` passes. eg. `lambda checked, a=x: self.notifyMe(a)`, as per comment in question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51522883/pyqt5-signal-slot-not-connecting-correctly-when-creating-widgets-in-a-loop

Comment: @Swedgin it is very old question and code uses `PySide` which (as I remeber) was using `PyQt4` and it could work differently than in `PyQt5`

Comment: I only mention it for future visitors. I'm using PyQt5 atm.

Comment: @Swedgin page not found, i'm looking for solution for pyqt5

Comment: @SadiqueKhan question in link was deleted but when you will have more points of reputation then you may see it.

Comment: @SadiqueKhan It was 4 years old question and it was closed as duplicate for questions [Python lambda doesn't remember argument in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723217/python-lambda-doesnt-remember-argument-in-for-loop), [Generating functions inside loop with lambda expression in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841268/generating-functions-inside-loop-with-lambda-expression-in-python), [Using lambda expression to connect slots in pyqt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35819538/using-lambda-expression-to-connect-slots-in-pyqt)