# Python3 tkinter batch to build button

Tags: python, tkinter

Win10 Python3.83

I hope that after clicking button, the corresponding message will pop up, but when this program runs, it is found that a message will be issued when the button is created, but there will be no message when clicked.How to solve it.

```sh
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox as msg

def cbClicked(cbname):
    print(cbname)
    msg.showinfo('click', cbname)

cb_list = ['cmd1', 'cmd2', 'cmd3']
win = tk.Tk()

for inx, cbname in enumerate(cb_list):
    tk.Button(win, width=10, height=1, text=cbname, command = cbClicked(cbname)).grid(row=0, column=inx)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Change `command=cbClicked(cbname)` to `command=lambda name=cbname: cbClicked(name)`.

Comment: could you tell me how this works,or where to understand it

Comment: See [python-lambda-in-a-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837486/python-lambda-in-a-loop)
or [python-lambda-doesnt-remember-argument-in-for-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723217/python-lambda-doesnt-remember-argument-in-for-loop).

Answer (score 1):

`command` option in `tk.Button` should be a function, not the result of function. You should pass the function name. At the same time, you need to pass argument, so define a lambda function for it.

Replace this line

```py
tk.Button(win, width=10, height=1, text=cbname, command = cbClicked(cbname)).grid(row=0, column=inx)
```

with this

```py
tk.Button(win, width=10, height=1, text=cbname, command = lambda x=cbname: cbClicked(x)).grid(row=0, column=inx)
```